# How delete a row with php in mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, dropdown, delete-row

I have this code and i'm doing a dropdown to people choose what notice they want to delete, but i don't know what is wrong in my code......i'm new..so sorry for my ignorance

PHP code:

```
<?php

include('configdb.php')
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
$query_delete = "DELETE from artigos where idartigos >0";
    $resultado_delete = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query_delete) or 
die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

if($resultado_delete)
    {

        echo "
        <script language='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Notícia eliminada com sucesso. Clique para voltar à página inicial.')
        window.location.href='index.php';
        </script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "
        <script language='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Não foi possível apagar a sua notícia. Tente novamente, sff. Clique para voltar à página inicial.')
        window.location.href='index.php';
        </script>";
    }
}
?>
```

HTML CODE:

```
<h1>Apagar notícia</h1>                 


                    <a>Notícias disponíveis</a><br><br>
                        <select name="delete" style="width:332px">
                            <?php echo $artigos; ?>
                        </select><br><br>                           

                        <p>eliminar
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" action= "delete.php" value="delete" />
                         </p>
```

[This is how it looks:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBxJy.jpg)

Comment: You have to fix form in html code https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: Alright... Where's the form? At least you need to specify the method. @NareshTeli She's using the new version.

Comment: I provide link for you .just read it you get ,how to write form in html ;

Comment: @NareshTeli Dude, seriously? Did you understand what I told you just now? LoL. That's new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
            <form action="delete.php">
 <select name="delete">
<option value=" ">blank</option>
<option value=" <?php echo $artigos; ?> "> <?php echo $artigos; ?> </option>
 </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in E:\xampp\htdocs\agreen\HTML\backoffice\delete.php on line 4

Comment: Semicolon (;) after include and change $_POST TO $_GET

Comment: Now it shows everything blank........i click and that's alright, but after that everything appears blank. Goes to delet.php and that's correct but appears blank

Comment: ; mistake in js , use text in if-else for test